# Inserting fields from different tables using query based forms. MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm creating a `form` in `MS Access 2007`. The `form` is pulling from a single `parent table`. It also contains a `sub-form` that is pulling from a `query`. The `query` is itself pulling from the `child table` associated to the parent and a related `table` called `t_item`.

I've created a `lookup field` on the `child table` relating back to `t_item` in order to auto fill in fields on the `form`. This all works wonderfully.

My issues is this, the values that in the `query` that are pulled from `t_item` by my `lookup field` are not getting pulled in the `child table`. I'm not really sure where I need to go to fix this issue. I keep looking for something that will allow me to control the `writing` of data for the `sub-form`, but nothing appears to be working.

This is the query

```
 SELECT 
        [t_export_details].[Export ID]
    ,   [t_export_details].[ItemLookup]
    ,   [t_item].[Description]
    ,   [t_item].[HACCP]
    ,   [t_item].[Species]
    ,   [t_item].[Maturity]
    ,   [t_item].[Frozen / Shelf Storeable]
    ,   [t_item].[Package Type]
    ,   [t_export_details].[Package Count]
    ,   [t_export_details].[Net Weight]
    ,   [t_export_details].[Marks]
    ,   [t_export_details].[Establishment Number] 
FROM t_item INNER JOIN t_export_details ON t_item.[Item ID]
```

Here is an example of the current results. The wanted outcome is for the fields being pulled from `t_item` in the query to be carried over onto the `child table`. This is a snippet of how the `child` currently looks after "creating" the record from the form.

[image: You can see that the fields being pulled from <code>t_item</code> are remaining blank]

So after some comments, I've altered the SQL Statement. This is how it looks now.

```
SELECT 
  t_export_details.[Export ID]
, t_export_details.ItemLookup
, t_item.Description
, t_item.HACCP
, t_item.Species
, t_item.Maturity
, t_item.[Frozen / Shelf Storeable]
, t_item.[Package Type]
, t_export_details.[Package Count]
, t_export_details.[Net Weight]
, t_export_details.Marks
, t_export_details.[Establishment Number]
FROM t_item INNER JOIN t_export_details 
ON (t_item.[Item ID] = t_export_details.ItemLookup) AND (t_item.[Item ID] = t_export_details.[Item ID]);
```

But this is still not writing across to the `child table` `t_export_details`

Here is the query design view on Access 2007

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged with SQL Server? Please remove the tag, if SQL Server isn't related to this question or edit your question and explain *how* it is related, if it is.

Comment: The values from the `t_item` table are not ment to be saved in the child table. The only value to be saved there is the lookup value.

Comment: Yes, but how do I alter this to get the `t_item` values to get carried across?

Comment: Inner join seems incorrect. Try this `FROM t_item INNER JOIN t_export_details ON t_item.[Item ID]=[t_export_details].[ItemLookup]`

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted the SQL tag, that was correct. -- You need a JOIN with your child table to pull values from there.

Comment: I've updated the answer in response to comments. The `child table` is `t_export_details` @Andre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution below.

Overview: `Access` doesn't allow editing of `many-to-one` relationships. It does not check whether your query output creates a `one-to-one` relationship. Basic solution is to update after user has entered data using a `macro` triggered by a `button` on the `main report`.

Breakdown by **Section.**

**Final `query` for `subreport`**

```
SELECT t_export_details.[Export ID]
, t_export_details.ItemLookup
, t_item.Description
, t_item.HACCP
, t_item.Species
, t_item.Maturity
, t_item.[Frozen Shelf Storeable]
, t_item.[Package Type]
, t_export_details.[Package Count]
, t_export_details.[Net Weight]
, t_export_details.Marks
, t_export_details.[Establishment Number]
FROM (t_item INNER JOIN t_export_details ON t_item.[Item ID] = t_export_details.ItemLookup) 
INNER JOIN t_export ON t_export_details.[Export ID] = t_export.[Export ID];
```

Nothing much changed here. Main issue is using a `Lookup` field as a `join` condition. After this experience paired with what I have read online, I would generally recommend against ever `joining` on a lookup value. However, it was necessary to keep it in my case for reporting reasons.

**`Update query` to run on button press in `main report`**

```
UPDATE t_item INNER JOIN t_export_details ON t_item.[Item ID]=t_export_details.ItemLookup 
SET t_export_details.[Item ID] = [t_item].[Item ID]
, t_export_details.HACCP = [t_item].[HACCP]
, t_export_details.Species = [t_item].[Species]
, t_export_details.[Frozen Shelf Storeable] = [t_item].[Frozen Shelf Storeable]
, t_export_details.[Package Type] = [t_item].[Package Type]
WHERE (((t_export_details.[Export ID])=[Forms]![USDAExport]![Export ID]));
```

Nothing too interesting about the `update` or `join` statements. Take note of the `where` clause for naming conventions in `access 2007`/`vba`

**Macro for button in `main report`**

[image: Button Macro]

`saveRecord` saves the `main report` record. `Requery` is required here in order to force a hidden save on the `sub report` record. If this is not done, then the `update query` runs before the `lookup` field has been `updated` by `access`. This results in the `update query` doing effectively nothing until it is pressed again. `setWarnings` = `No` is important to prevent the user from being prompted while executing the `query`. Hopefully everything else is self explanatory. `Close` is called `closeWindow` in versions of `ms-access` made after the Bush presidency. Pretty nice `macro` tool inside `ms-access`

**Output data after solution**

Note that all `output` data is fake lies generated by me.

[image: Final Data]

**Takeaways**

- Access 2007 remains a robust if frustrating visual interface program. This comes as a disappointment to many devs who had hoped to never need to learn anything created before 2012.
- Event/visually oriented programming is uniquely challenging to ask good questions about in an online setting.
- I should begin selling myself as a back-end only dev.

Finally, my most helpful resources

1. Everyone who left a helpful comment or clarifying question
2. How to use a `query` for a `form`: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/use-a-query-as-the-record-source-for-a-form-or-report-e54251f3-57ca-4a7d-8e77-e498966cd41b 
   Pay particular attention to "When can I edit a query?" section.
3. Parameter pass-ins for `queries`: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-parameters-in-queries-forms-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356
4. How to construct an `update` `query`: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/access-cookbook/0596000847/ch01s06.html
5. Create a `Macro` to run a `query` http://www.databasedev.co.uk/open-query-macro.html
6. Turn off warnings for a `run query` macro: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-action-query-confirmation-messages-on-or-off-e58e4bba-9d54-4b9d-b962-9eca048e5335#__use_a_macro